# Jquery ui autocomplete- not listing the values from remote source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to use jquery autocomplete feature in my MVC5 view.

**Script:**

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("GetJsonData?term=" + request.term, function (data) {

                response(data);

            });
        }
    });
```

I am getting the data as expected inside the source function.

```
data=[Object { label="test",  value=1}, Object { label="test2",  value=2}]//Checked with firebug
```

But the autocomplete control is not listing the values at all. It works fine when I specify a local data source.

**Update**

This is what I found in the browser debugger;

**> response**

**<** jquery-1.10.2.js:840 function () {
            return fn.apply( context || this, args.concat( core_slice.call( arguments ) ) );
        }

**> data**

**<** Object {label: "tst", value: "tstvalue"}

**> response(data);**

**<** undefined

As you can see response(data) returns 'undefined'. Is that expected? Or Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Is the success function fired? Tried adding an error callback?

Comment: @IrvinDominin Yes, the success function fired . I put a dubugger before response(data), and checked its value

Comment: Try to return the data as an array

Comment: I tried every valid format (including array of values) described in the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Have you tried to use the $.ajax function instead of $.getJSON like its done in this example?: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp